# payment initiation with idenity server 4

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

I am trying to do a payment initiation example similar to Paypal using OpenID connect and identity server 4 in .net Core, I have created three project identity server, bank API, and a merchant APP, so when the user presses the checkout button, the user will be redirected to sign-in page like so:

```
  public IActionResult Checkout()
        {
            return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = "/Home/Success",
       
            }, "oidc");
        }
```

what I want now is to get the checkout information like the amount to pay and show it on the consent page of the identity server.
please help.

Answer (score 0):

The consent page is not meant to confirm payments or things like that. That should be handled inside your application instead.

What you do inside IdentityServer is just to authenticate the user.

Keep the logic separate => Separation of concerns.

Comment: Yes I know, I just need to show the user a message telling him that he is about to pay this amount of money on the consent page, once the user gives consent for this, the merchant app can call the bank API